Should no order preference at all be given to the selected answer?
Why is no preference given at all to the selected answer in terms of the order listed? It seems that the OP has the most to say about whether their specific question was answered, and thus, a selected answer should have at least some priority over others that are not selected.
I understand this can be a little embarrassing for the site if the OP is especially biased where their answer gets -1 vote and the next answer gets 20, but I think it's nevertheless informative to see right away what the OP found to be the most helpful response. It's not hard to see what the actual most valuable response is right below it.
In my own case regarding the following question: Grace of God vs the Grace of the One Man Jesus Christ (Rom 5:15)
I finally selected a very recent answer 3 years after originally posting it. But since the selected answer is no longer preferred in order it is set all the way at the bottom and is less likely to even be looked at, let alone voted on, even though it is the selected answer.
Now, full disclosure: I posted my own answer, but I think this is problematic, even if I didn't post my own answer, that the selected answer, especially when it comes years later, receives no boost and is thus ordered at the bottom receiving near zero visability.
Is it really the right choice that the selected answer receives no preference at all?

The pinning and ordering of "correct" answers was changed in 2021. There is indeed preference given.
Read all about it: Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers

Man... That's wild. I'm just now noticing.

Ok read the whole thing. According to the post. Pinning the selected answer remained the default. No immediate change was made. Some change had  to specifically happen with this site specfically.

There is supposed to be a process by which this happens involving community agreement. Did that happen here?

@Austin - I've been here that whole time and can't recall any site specific changes of this nature.

@Stevecanhelp. Huh. So no idea when the selected answer became unpinned? Thanks for helping feel like I'm not crazy here.

@Austin no, you're not crazy. There is some kind of multi-layered aspect to it. Part of the discussion involved stale "correct" correct answers from 10 years ago that were outdated while high-vote, accurate, and current answers remained below them. So, time also may have been a factor. If the community wants, we could ping staff about it.

Thanks, I'd be very interested to understand why the change.
